# How to display image on the defined <Area> coordinates

Tags: html, imagemap

We can  use image maps to create hyperlinks...

but is it also possible to use an area segment of an image map to fill it up with another image.

If yes then how we do it? there is no img tag in  tag!!

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS absolute positioning and put the image anywhere you want.